# Setting a custom browser as default browser in blackberry

Tags: java, blackberry, blackberry-eclipse-plugin

I have made my own browser - now what I am trying to do is set my own browser as the default browser so that when a user clicks on the blackberry default browser, my brower will open.

Is it possible to do this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, you can't replace the system browser with your own browser.

And polling in the background like the other answer says is bad idea for several reasons, including needless use of your battery charge.

Comment: Polling that uses the radio (e.g.) api requests is a large drain, so is polling that wakes the display, but do you know how much drain getVisibleApplications() would use when it fails to match the browser case?

Comment: Here's an example http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/Create-a-Background-Application/ta-p/445226  what are the several reasons this is bad?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with background applications, I use them all the time on the BlackBerry. But your example is very bad because it's busy waiting, always running and checking whether the browser is in the foreground. Most background apps are idle most of the time. Also, as a user I would hate having that kind of dialog popup all the time.

Comment: I was hoping you had an answer to the drain on the battery question from that sort of background process. Other than it's bad. (5 seconds in the RIM example) I think I will put it to the test, I would like to know how much it shortens battery life.

Comment: I agree on the annoyance of the popup, I wouldn't like that either :)

Comment: Since I just don't so this kind of thing, I have never tried to quantify the drain. Also, you will be slowing down the device overall as it spends CPU time on this task.

Comment: Hold on a moment... Comparing a memory resident value every x seconds (which is essentially what we're talking about) is not going to be noticeable on a BlackBerry CPU :)

Comment: You said "at a fairly quick interval", not every few seconds... yes, if it was only every few seconds then it wouldn't be much of a drain. But it also wouldn't be very responsive.

Comment: To me in this case "at a fairly quick interval" is every few seconds. Sorry I wasn't specific. Yes there would be a variable delay between opening the browser and the detection. I did say it wasn't exactly as he wanted but it was the closet thing I could think of.

Comment: +1 for not being able to replace the system browser, I do believe that is correct.

Answer (score 2):

Interesting question :)

I cannot think of a way to do it exactly as you've asked... but you could try something like
poll from the background at a fairly quick interval using `ApplicationManager.getApplicationManager().getVisibleApplications();`

And if the web browser comes to the foreground your process launches your dialog.
E.g. "Would you like to use my super-duper browser instead? [yes] [no]"

Cheers

Ray

Comment: By "fairly quick interval" I really meant around 5 seconds, also see http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/Create-a-Background-Application/ta-p/445226 for an example background app